# Django DRF+ EmberJS2.6 related model data

Tags: django, ember.js, django-rest-framework, ember-data, single-page-application

I have django app that handle restAPIs with following JSON response, also i have ember app with [django-ember-adapter](https://github.com/dustinfarris/ember-django-adapter). The problem is i can not get related items in the sub route(`http://localhost:8000/api/projects/4/tasks`) of API. I can get projects by `http://localhost:8000/api/projects/4`. Am i have to include task in project's django model in API?, I have tried using `links` in serializer but seems it's not working.

How do i get **project's tasks** successfully?

json response on `http://localhost:8000/api/projects/4` i can get this by `this.store.findRecord('project', params.project_id)`:

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "title": "test1 project",
    "description": "some project",
    "owner": "test1"
}
```

json response on `http://localhost:8000/api/projects/4/tasks`:

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "title": "4th",
            "description": "4tg description"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "title": "",
            "description": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

django models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    """Canara project """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default='')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='projects', null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=55, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    due_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    assign = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, null=True)
```

serializer:

```
class ProjectViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint for project
    """
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication]
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsOwner)
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Get user's project
        """
        return Project.objects.filter(members__member=self.request.user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        """
        Set user as an owner when create project
        """
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)

class TaskViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    """
    API for task
    """
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
```

---

ember app's project model

```
export default Model.extend({
  title: attr(),
  description: attr(),
});
```

ember app's task model

```
export default Model.extend({
  title: attr(),
  description: attr(),
  due_date: attr('date'),
  assign: belongsTo('user'),
  project: belongsTo('project')
});
```

**Update**
I have tried embedded record mixin but no luck

in the serializer:

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'owner', 'tasks')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create project using given validated data
        """
        return Project.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update project title description
        """
        instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
        instance.description = validated_data.get(
                'description', instance.description)
        instance.save()


class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    project = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Project.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'due_date', 'assign', 'project')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Task.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
        instance.description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
        instance.due_date = validated_data.get('due_date', instance.due_date)
        instance.assign = validated_data.get('assign', instance.assign)
```

i've tried links in this way:

```
import DRFSerializer from './drf';

export default DRFSerializer.extend({
  normalizeFindAllResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
    console.log(payload)
    payload.links: {
        tasks: tasks
      };
    });

    return this._super(...arguments);
  }
});
```

Comment: where is ur django DRF ? I don't see any code related to that ...

Comment: @Mox oh sorry let me update the post

Comment: have u tried accessing the task url directly from browser?

Comment: @Mox 
yes, it shows following json response in `http://localhost:8000/api/projects/4/tasks` 

   {
  "count": 2,
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
   {
    "id": 5,
    "title": "4th",
    "description": "4tg description"
   },
   {
    "id": 6,
    "title": "",
    "description": ""
   }
  ]
 }

Comment: Links definitely the way to go for something like this.  Have you taken a look at the documentation?  http://dustinfarris.com/ember-django-adapter/hyperlinked-related-fields/

Comment: @dustinfarris like how??? can you show me some example??? I've seen documentation and using links like this
    
`import DRFSerializer from './drf';

export default DRFSerializer.extend({
  normalizeFindAllResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
    console.log(payload)
    payload.links: {
        tasks: tasks
      };
    });

    return this._super(...arguments);
  }
});
`

Comment: @Zorig the documentation has a pretty good example.  i'm not sure which part is breaking down for you.  why don't you reach out to me on ember slack and we can work through this together.

Comment: @dustinfarris alright that would be very nice